# C++ - efficiently reading a file sequentially

Tags: c++

I need to sequentially read a file in C++, dealing with 4 characters at a time (but it's a sliding window, so the next character is handled along with the 3 before it). I could read chunks of the file into a buffer (I know `mmap()` will be more efficient but I want to stick to platform-independent plain C++), or I could read the file a character at a time using `std::cin.read()`. The file could be arbitrary large, so reading the whole file is not an option.

Which approach is more efficient?

Comment: It is entirely possible that the code underlying `std::cin.read()` does its own buffering, and reads multiple bytes at a time. The design of the `istream` spec allows for such things (see also, `readsome`).

Comment: @Rook I thought about that, but there are no guarantees to how large the buffer is, and besides all the calls in between must have a large overhead anyway?

Comment: It shouldn't take you long to do some profiling ;)

Comment: Uhm… measure? There are not that many options. For portable code you can read 1byte at a time, but you can also read chunks (4kb, 8kb, 16kb …). Setup a test and try them out. Compare them with `mmap`, use different approaches to read the buffer…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient method is to read a lot of data into memory using the fewest function calls or requests.

The objective is to keep the hard drive spinning.  One of the bottlenecks is waiting for the hard drive to spin to correct speed.  Another is trying to locate the sectors on the hard drive where your requested data lives.  A third bottleneck is collisions with the database and memory.

So I vote for the `read` method into a buffer and search the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Determine what the largest chunk of data you can read at a time. Then read the file by the chunks.

Say you can only deal with `2K` characters at a time. Then, use:

```
std::ifstream if(filename);
char chunk[2048];
while ( if.read(chunk, 2048)) )
{
   std::streamsize nread = in.gcount();
   // Process nread number of characters of the chunk.
}
```

Comment: I thought 2k was 2048 bytes, although I could be wrong. :-)

Comment: Is this any more efficient than the in-built buffering of `std::cin` that Rook pointed out?

Comment: As Thomas Matthews answers, reading efficiently should come first, and that means reading a sizable amount into memory in one operation. Then you can process it (not read it) 4 characters at a time.

Comment: I suggest reading at least 32k (32,768) bytes at a time. This is the cluster size for large partitions, so the sectors will be sequential, even in a fragmented file. Also reading the file in binary will eliminate any overhead in converting end of line sequences on dos / windows type text files, which use \r\n for end of line which get replaced by just \n if not reading in binary mode. The code would have to ignore any \r if present and go by \n. I don't recall if there are any current systems that use \r for end of line. (in hex \r = 0x0d, \n = 0x0a). Unicode text files would be another issue.